# KnockoutJS Model AMD pattern, with subscribe option for any property

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, amd

I am new to knockoutjs, coming from the AngularJS world.
I am trying to use AMD patterns to help me organize my JavaScript with Require.js.

I have a "Model.js" which I load with require in multiple views.
I would like to set properties outside of the Model and subscribe to changes as well.

Here is the example of my Model:

```
    define(['knockout', 'komapping'], function (ko, komapping) {    
         var self = this;
         self.model = komapping.fromJS({});  

        init = function () {        
            $.getJSON("some api call", function (data) {                            
                komapping.fromJS(data, self.model);
            });     
        };  

        self.obsModel.someProperty.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log('new property value',newValue);
        });

        init();

        ko.applyBindings(self.model);

        return self;
});
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question you are asking.  If you are just looking for a code review, this isn't a good site for that.  however, if you have a specific problem, you should attach the error message(s) and describe what you have tried to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I have properties that more than one model needs access to I create another JS module.  For example I might put it in config.js (love you J. Papa).

```
define('config',['jquery','ko'], function ($, ko) {
    var
        prop1 = ko.observable(),
        prop2 = ko.observable();

    return {
        prop1: prop1,
        prop2: prop2
    };
});
```

Then in my model I would have

```
define('myModel',['ko','config'], function (ko, config) {
    var
        somePropToBindTo = ko.observable(),

        init = function () {
            config.prop1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                console.log('new property value',newValue);
            });
        };

    init();

    return {
        somePropToBindTo: somePropToBindTo
    };
});
```